# openAI Cart Pole 'Solved' meaning

Tags: deep-learning

What does it mean to 'solve' the openAI CartPole problem? [Here](https://gym.openai.com/evaluations/eval_EIcM1ZBnQW2LBaFN6FY65g/) it says that solved means that:

> ...when the agent obtains an average reward of at least 195.0 over 100
>   consecutive episodes.)

but the solution in the same link was solved after 85 episodes? How can it be solved in 85 episodes if we need an average reward of 195 in over 100 episodes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at "total episodes" next to "episodes to solve", it says 185, which is the initial 85 + the 100 required to declare it a "reliable" solution. So it *initially* solved the problem after 85 episodes and maintained the average reward for 100 episodes.